# IE9 on Windows 7, ipv6.google.com does not work, but in chrome it does?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, ipv6

I have an ipv6 connection, I get addresses, DNS is working and I can ping (with ping -6) ipv6.google.com. I can get to and use google in Chrome, but it does not work at all in IE9. It just says that the page is not accessible. Any one run into this? The computer is running Win7 32 bit.

Comment: Do you need to use IE9 for any specific reason? IMO, Chrome trumps IE as a browser.

Comment: Of course it does, but unfortunately I need to verify it works.

Comment: Have you tried deleting then re-installing IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried what Microsoft say about IE and IPv6 websites?
There are certain requirements that must be met.

This document details them:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740593

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think of right now are:

- IE is using a proxy server or something like that
- Your anti-virus or internet-security software is integrating with IE and messing IPv6 up

The second one still happens too much unfortunately :(